# I am trying to get a multiselect dropdown with checkbox, facing some issue while populating items and getting allChecked work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have followed a fiddle

[Fiddle with multiselect](http://jsfiddle.net/7oxz63t5/)

and modified it. My fiddle is -
[Modified Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SeemaMishra/7oxz63t5/10/)

I am working on it to selectAll/DeselectAll functionality in the drop down.
I have made the Items array as observable and pushing values returned from server.

Where i am doing it wrong.

```js
function CheckableBox(label, isChecked) {
  this.label = label;
  this.isChecked = ko.observable(isChecked || false);
}
var authTypeArray = [{name:'All Therapy''},{name:'P Therapy''},{name:'O Therapy'},{name:'S Therapy'},{name:'R Therapy'}];

function ViewModel() {
 this.Items = ko.observableArray();
  this.specialtyViewArray = authTypeArray;

  for (var id = 0; id < this.specialtyViewArray.length; id++) {
    var name = this.specialtyViewArray[id].name;
    this.Items.push(new CheckableBox(name, false));
  }
  
  this.selectedItems = ko.observable([]);

 /* Includes only the checked items */
  this.tempSelection = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return this.Items.filter(function(item) {
      return item.isChecked();
    });
  }, this);
  
  /* Builds a comma separated string of selected items */
  this.selectedItemsStr = ko.pureComputed(function() {
   var str = this.selectedItems()
     .map(function(item) {
       return item.label;
      })
      .join(", ")
      
      return str || "-- No options selected --";
  }, this);
  
  /* Determines whether the selectable options are displayed. */
  this.optionsShown = ko.observable(false);
  
  this.optionsShown.subscribe(function() {
   this.updateSelections();
  }, this);
  
  this.confirmSelection();
  this.checkAll = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
      var firstUnchecked = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.Items(), function (item)           {
        return item.isChecked(false);
      });
      return firstUnchecked == null;
    },
    write: function (value) {
      ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.Items(), function (item) {
       item.isChecked(value);
      });
    }
  });

};

ViewModel.prototype.toggleOptions = function() {
 this.optionsShown(!this.optionsShown());
};

ViewModel.prototype.confirmSelection = function() {
 this.selectedItems(this.tempSelection());
  this.closeOptions();
};

ViewModel.prototype.closeOptions = function() {
  this.optionsShown(false);
}

ViewModel.prototype.updateSelections = function() {
 var selection = this.selectedItems();
  this.Items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.isChecked(selection.indexOf(item));
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.main-container {
  width: 400px;
}

.main-container,
.select-container {
  position: relative;
}

.select-container {
  height: 2em;
}

select,
.select-container::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.select-container::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.options-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  display: none;
}

.options-container.shown {
  display: block;
}

label {
  display: block;
  padding: .2em;
}

label:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.checked {
  background: #568ECB;
  color: white;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-top: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
  background: #F6F6F6;
}

.button-container button {
  margin: .4em;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="select-container" data-bind="click: toggleOptions">
    <select data-bind="options: [selectedItemsStr]"></select>
  </div>
  <div class="options-container" data-bind="css: { 'shown': optionsShown }">
    <div class="options" data-bind="foreach: Items">
      <!-- ko if: $index() == 0 -->
      <label data-bind="css: { 'checked': isChecked }">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkAll">
        <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
      </label>
      <!-- /ko -->
      <!-- ko if: $index() != 0 -->
      <label data-bind="css: { 'checked': isChecked }">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked">
        <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
      </label>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
      <button type="button" data-bind="click: confirmSelection">OK</button>
      <button type="button" data-bind="click: closeOptions">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a lot of mistakes:

`name:'All Therapy''` What is?

`this.Items` - you are defined this variable like observableArray (function), but trying to apply to it the array's methods like this `this.Items.filter`

In your computed function you have wrong context. You could use [owner options](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-reference.html).

In your html template you have undefined binding

`<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkAll">`

`checkAll` isn't exist in your `CheckableBox` model. You need to use `$parent.checkAll` instead.

Here simple working code:

```
function CheckableBox(label, isChecked) {
  this.label = label;
  this.isChecked = ko.observable(isChecked || false);
}

function ViewModel(data) {
  this.items = data.map(function(item) {
      return new CheckableBox(item.name, false);
  });

  this.selectedItems = ko.observable([]);

  this.tempSelection = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return this.items.filter(function(item) {
      return item.isChecked();
    });
  }, this);

  this.selectedItemsStr = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var str = this.selectedItems()
      .map(function(item) {
        return item.label;
      })
      .join(", ")

      return str || "-- No options selected --";
  }, this);

  this.optionsShown = ko.observable(false);
  this.optionsShown.subscribe(function() {
    this.updateSelections();
  }, this);

  this.confirmSelection(); 

  this.checkAll = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function () {
      return this.items.every(function(item) {
        return item.isChecked();
      });
    },
    write: function (value) {
      this.items.forEach(function (item) {
        item.isChecked(value);
      });
    },
    owner: this
  });
};

ViewModel.prototype.toggleOptions = function() {
  this.optionsShown(!this.optionsShown());
};

ViewModel.prototype.confirmSelection = function() {
  this.selectedItems(this.tempSelection());
  this.closeOptions();
};

ViewModel.prototype.closeOptions = function() {
  this.optionsShown(false);
};

ViewModel.prototype.updateSelections = function() {
  var selection = this.selectedItems();
  this.items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.isChecked(~selection.indexOf(item));
  });
};

var authTypeArray = [
  { name:'All Therapy' },
  { name:'P Therapy' },
  { name:'O Therapy' },
  { name:'S Therapy' },
  { name:'R Therapy' }
];

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
```

I hope this will help you. [My modified Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzycnyqp/)

Comment: I tried your suggested changes and it is working perfectly. But in a case when I pass isChecked true  in chackableBox by default, All Therapy is not getting checked and then few behabiours are not working.

Comment: Awesome I did not see that condition.I modified it to http://jsfiddle.net/SeemaMishra/vw8d1xry/1/ how can I change it to show only All Therapy when all are selected rather than showing all therapy, p therapy, ......

Comment: Your code is different from my. Specifically, tempSelection function

Comment: Yes I changed it to show all Therapy in selected option list, but when all are selected I just want to show the All Therapy not the other items comma separated.

Comment: Hi @yurzui, In this case only what I have is this multiselect in a popover. my popover has table. table rows are filled with all the data I am getting from backend. Now I wanted to refresh the data based on items selected in the list. I have added codes part as comment and updated fiddle. Can you have a look at it?